# Two MYSQL statements with different columns names but from same table

Tags: mysql

I have this two MySQL statements from same table :

```
SELECT
    `table1`.`product_id` As product_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(table1.user_id)) AS NonebuyersNumber
FROM table1
WHERE status = 1 AND `ispaid` != 2
GROUP BY `table1`.`product_id`
```

[image]

The second statement is :

```
SELECT l
    `table1`.`product_id` As product_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(table1.user_id)) AS BuyersNumber
FROM table1
WHERE `ispaid` = 1
GROUP BY `table1`.`product_id`
```

[image]

The result that I want is a table like this one :

[image]

I tried to use Union but doesn't work because I have two different columns

Any idea how I can get this 3rd table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    product_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN status = 1 AND ispaid != 2
                        THEN user_id ELSE NULL END) AS NonebuyersNumber
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ispaid = 1 THEN user_id ELSE NULL END) AS BuyersNumber
FROM table1
WHERE
    (status = 1 AND ispaid != 2) OR 
    ispaid = 1
GROUP BY
    product_id;
```

This should work because both of your queries aggregate over the `product_id` and the only differences are the `WHERE` clauses.  We can combine the records from both queries and then use `CASE` expressions to target records intended for each original query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.product_id AS product_id
SELECT CASE WHEN t1.NonebuyersNumber IS NULL 
            THEN 0 
            ELSE t1.NonebuyersNumber 
            END 
    AS NonebuyersNumber,
SELECT CASE WHEN t2.BuyersNumber IS NULL 
            THEN 0 
            ELSE t2.BuyersNumber 
            END 
    AS BuyersNumber
FROM
(SELECT 
    `table1`.`product_id` As product_id , 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(table1.user_id)) AS NonebuyersNumber 
    FROM table1 WHERE status =1 
    AND `ispaid` != 2 
    GROUP BY `table1`.`product_id`) 
AS t1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
    `table1`.`product_id` As product_id , 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(table1.user_id)) AS BuyersNumber 
    FROM table1 WHERE `ispaid` = 1 
    GROUP BY `table1`.`product_id`) 
AS t2
ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id
```

Basically, you need following

- Join both the views on `product_id`
- Use `CASE` statements in select in case one of the buyers numbers is NULL